# SSL Certificate: Is an intermediate certificate always needed?

Tags: community, certificates, custom-domain

We recently purchased an SSL certificate for a custom domain. When we received it, the provider said we needed to also install an intermediate certificate.

There is an article called '[Merge a complete certificate chain for custom HTTPS domains](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000204513&language=en_US&type=1)' that explains how to load intermediate certificates, but we've had some issues with this.

The article says "*Some systems or browsers don't have trusted intermediate certificates. To resolve this, those certificates need to be installed and trusted.*"

My question is, given that the article says "*some systems or browsers*", does this mean in most cases, the intermediate certificate wouldn't be necessary (e.g. for newer browsers)?

Given the issues we're having loading the intermediate cert, I want to know if we can get away with not loading it.